# Adding a row with less values to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, row

Given an example dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

values = np.array([
    [0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 3],
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 ],
    [0, 0.5, 0, 0, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0],        
 ])

 indexes= 'a','b','c','d'

 columns='ab','bc','cd','de','ef','fg'

 df = pd.DataFrame(index=indexes,columns=columns, data=values)

 print(df)
```

which looks like:

```
    ab   bc   cd   de   ef   fg
a  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0  3.0
b  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  2.0  1.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0
```

desired output:

```
    ab   bc   cd   de   ef   fg
a  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0  3.0
b  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  2.0  1.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0
e  Nan  Nan  Nan  NAn  7.0  4.0
```

Is it somehow possible to add a row where are displayed only the sums of the two last columns? (Of course, below the respective columns)

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: last two columns or last two rows? Maybe give your desired output.

Comment: Good point, @Psidom...

Comment: Excuse me, what I was meaming is that I want to add a row, where I display the sum of the 2nd last column's values (below the 2nd column), and the sum of the last column's values (below the last column). Keeping the other cells of the row empty. Hope to be clear now!

Comment: Can you give your desired output as a table?

Comment: I've added the desired output, I put Nan but I would like to those cells to be completly empty, but I guess it's impossible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: ohhh. Thanks for the clarification. You create a new row and assign that with the sum of the last two columns. The `iloc` indexer is of the format [row,col]. So we want `:` all rows but only the final two columns `-2:`.

```
df.loc['e'] = df.iloc[:,-2:].sum()
```

Result:

```
>>> df
   ab   bc   cd   de   ef   fg
a  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0  3.0
b  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  2.0  1.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0
e  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  7.0  4.0
```

---

Old answer:
I assume you mean the last two rows...

You can use [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) here

```
pd.concat([df,df.iloc[-2,:] + df.iloc[-1:]])
```

Result:

```
>>> pd.concat([df,df.iloc[-2,:] + df.iloc[-1:]])
    ab   bc   cd   de   ef   fg
a  0.0  0.5  1.0  0.0  0.0  3.0
b  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
c  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  2.0  1.0
d  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  4.0  0.0
d  0.0  0.5  0.0  0.0  6.0  1.0
```

Comment: @Paauulus: you're very welcome. Happy coding to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use loc

```
df.loc['sum_c_d'] = df[-2:].sum()


        ab  bc  cd  de  ef  fg
a       0   0.5 1   0   0   3
b       1   0.0 0   1   1   0
c       0   0.5 0   0   2   1
d       0   0.0 0   0   4   0
sum_c_d 0   0.5 0   0   6   1
```